# Hover effect on 4 triangle div

Tags: html, css, hover, geometry

here is problem: http://jsfiddle.net/Coffeeh/SVwsW/

```
.a{
   width: 0px;
   height: 0px; 
}
.L {
    border-top: 50px solid transparent;
    border-left: 50px solid #ff0000;
    border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
    float: left;
}
.L:hover{
border-left: 50px solid #ffcc00;
}
.T {
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    border-top: 50px solid #ff0000;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
}
.T:hover{
border-top: 50px solid #ffcc00;
}
.B {
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 50px solid #ff0000;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
}
.B:hover{
border-bottom: 50px solid #ffcc00;
}
.R {
    border-top: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 50px solid #ff0000;
    border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
    float: right;
}
.R:hover{
border-right: 50px solid #ffcc00;
}
```

Any ideas how to make this 4 triangle divs work perfect on hover?

Option with 1 4-border div doens not match requirements

Solved: http://jsfiddle.net/Coffeeh/tg3ER/

Comment: Your question is too vague. What hover effect are you trying to achieve?

Comment: looks like the left and right elements are covering the top and bottom elements. try different way to create triangle elements. may be using css3.

Comment: just solved by myself http://jsfiddle.net/Coffeeh/tg3ER/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just solved by using two div, one with "overflow: hidden" and another with "transform: rotate(45deg)"

works perefect for me

here is fiddle:
jsfiddle.net/Coffeeh/tg3ER

Answer (score 0):

I cant see how you would do this with borders as they are block level elements and need to be quadratic as a block level element.

I can suggest using an image an image mapping.

```
<img src="/images/map.gif" alt="HTML Map" border="0" usemap="#map"/>

<map name="map">
   <area shape="poly" 
            coords="74,0,113,29,98,72,52,72,38,27"
            href="index.htm" alt="area1" />

   <area shape="poly" 
            coords="22,83,126,125"
            href="index.htm" alt="area2" />

   <area shape="poly" 
            coords="73,168,32"
            href="index.htm" alt="area3" />
</map>
```